# Unitary representations of lattices

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, lattices, p-adic-groups, arithmetic-groups

Let $G$ be a simple linear group over a non-archimedean local field $F$.
Assume that the split-rank over $F$ is at least 2.
Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $G$. Then $\Gamma$ is a finitely generated Kazhdan group.

My question is this:
Does $\Gamma$ admit a finite-dimensional unitary representation $\rho$ such that the image $\rho(\Gamma)$ is infinite?

Comment: Probably yes. Let $p$ be the residual characteristic of $F$. By arithmeticity, I think $\Gamma$ is commensurable with $H(\mathbf{Z}[1/p])$ for some semisimple $\mathbf{Q}$-group $H$ (I'm not sure arithmeticity says exactly this), with $G(F)$ isomorphic (up to finite index and finite kernel) to a cocompact direct factor in $H(\mathbf{Q}_p)$. Then $H(\mathbf{R})$ is compact, so inclusion $H(\mathbf{Z}[1/p])\subset H(\mathbf{R})\subset \mathrm{U}_n$ yield a faithful finite-dim unitary rep.

Comment: I also think that every representation $\Gamma\to\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{C})$ has an image with compact closure, by superrigidity (while there clearly exists such a faithful representation for some $n$).

Comment: Thanks! That helps. Cheers.

Comment: (I implicitly assumed $F$ of char. zero; indeed the conclusion is different in finite char., as explained in Venkataramana's more complete answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, always, if $\operatorname{char}(F)=0$ and never if $\operatorname{char}(F)\neq 0$. It is easy to see that it is enough to prove this when $G$ is simply connected as an algebraic group; we then assume $G$ is simply connected.

Suppose $\Gamma \subset G=G(F)$ is a lattice and $F$ is a non-archimedean local field with $char (F)=0$. By Margulis's arithmeticity theorem, $\Gamma $ is commensurate to $G_0(O_S)$ where  $G_0$ is an absolutely simple algebraic group defined over a number field $K$, $S$ is a finite set of places of $K$ including all the Archimedean ones, and for some place $v$ of $K$, we have $F\simeq K_v$ with an isomorphism  $G(F)\simeq G_o(K_v)$. Since the projection of $\Gamma $ to $G_0(K_v)$ is to be discrete, we have $G_0 (K\otimes _{\mathbb Q} {\mathbb R})$ is compact. But, the map  of $\Gamma $ in $G_0(K \otimes _{\mathbb Q} {\mathbb R})$ is faithful, and the latter compact real algebraic group has a faithful unitary finite dimensional representation (this is essentially the argument of @YCor in the comments).

Suppose $\operatorname{char}(F)>0$. Since the rank of $G$ over $F$ is at least two, by super-rigidity in finite characteristic (due to myself and also proved in Margulis' book later), every finite dimensional representation of $\Gamma $ into $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ has finite image. Hence $\Gamma $ cannot have infinite image finite dimensional (unitary) representations.